# Change dir colour in bash output

Tags: osx, ls, colors

Under Mac OSX, I am trying to change the dir colour when `ls` outputs in the bash shell. So I placed this line at the end of my `.bashrc` file and reloaded.

`LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;32:' ; export LS_COLORS`
`. ~/.bashrcc`

The output of `echo "$LS_COLORS"` is 
`:di=0;35::di=0;35::di=0;32:`

But I am not getting the light green I am expecting. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Mac uses BSD `ls`.  See `man ls` for details.
2. The format of `LS_COLORS` is different.

   Specifically, see `LESS='+/^[[:space:]]*LSCOLORS' man ls`
3. The variable name isn't even `LS_COLORS`, it's `LSCOLORS`.

The links I found that were most helpful in figuring this out were [this blog post](https://softwaregravy.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/ls-colors-for-mac/), and [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031025162727485) which was linked to from the blog post.

The default value for `LSCOLORS` is `exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad`.  To leave everything at its default color except for directories, and make those green instead of blue, put the following in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LSCOLORS=cxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

You will also need to either set the `CLICOLOR` variable (with `export CLICOLOR=`) or alias `ls` to `ls -G`.  But in your screenshot above you do have color output, so I'm assuming you've done one of those already.

---

**Original Answer:**

On Mac OS, `ls` takes the `-G` option to colorize output.

From `man ls` on a Mac:

```
 -G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining
         CLICOLOR in the environment.  (See below.)
```

Run `ls -G` and you'll get color output.

---

I also recommend adding:

```
alias ls='ls -GF'
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`.  That's the alias I have there.  The `-F` option adds the `/` after directory names, `*` after executables, etc.

Comment: I realized I misread the question; I was answering how to *enable* colors in `ls`, not how to change them.  I've tried fiddling with the value of `LS_COLORS` according to the manpage.  No luck yet.  However, please note that the format for `LS_COLORS` in BSD `ls` is very different from that of GNU `ls`.